# JavaScript for Random Numbers with Recursion

Tags: javascript, math, random, for-loop

I'm trying to create a javascript function that accepts 2 parameters `min` and `max` and generates a random number between the two integers.  That part is easy.

Where things get rough is that I need to create a conditional that says

```
function generateNum (min, max) {
  var randNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(max - min)+min);

  if (randNumber === max) {
    // store the result (probably in an array) and generate a new 
    // number with the same behavior as randNumber (e.g. it is also
    // stores it's total in the array and recursively "re-generates 
    // a new number until max is not hit)
  }
}
```

The idea is to recursive-ise this so that a running total of the number of max hits is stored, combined, and then returned.

For example: The script receives min / max parameters of 5/10 `generateNum(5,10){}`. If the value generated by `randNumber` were 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9 then there would be no recursion and the function would return that value. If the value generated by `randNumber` is `10`, then the value `10` is stored in an array and the function now "re-tries" recursively (meaning that as many times as 10 is generated, then that value is stored as an additional object in the array and the function re-tries).  When the process stops (which could be infinite but has a parabolically decreasing probability of repeating with each recursion).  The final number (5, 6, 7, 8, 9) would be added to the total of generated `max` values and the result would be returned.

Quite an unusual mathematic scenario, let me know how I can clarify if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: So what is the "stop" condition and what is the "recurse" condition? Just write that in the code as described.

Comment: Don't understand why you need recursion. Just use a `while` loop and a counter which you increment whenever you get `max`. Stop once you get a different number. The result is then `counter * max + randNumber` (or if you want to return an array that would be easy to create as well, but recursion is not needed either way).

Comment: so what exactly is the question, it seems as though you have all of the logic there?  Just store the number in an array that is at a higher scope level than your function and call generateNum(min,max); right afterwards.

Comment: Just thought you should know that your function will return 'min' only on extremely rare occasions. There's a proper function for random numbers in the answers, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That part is easy.

Not as easy as you think... The algorithm that you have is broken; it will almost never give you the minimum value. Use the `Math.floor` method instead, and add one to the range:

```
var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

To do this recursively is simple, just call the method from itself:

```
function generateNum (min, max) {
  var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min + 1)) + min;
  if (randNumber == max) {
    randNumber += generateNum(min, max);
  }
  return randNumber;
}
```

You can also solve this without recursion:

```
function generateNum (min, max) {
  var randNumber = 0;
  do {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min + 1)) + min;
    randNumber += num;
  } while (num == max);
  return randNumber;
}
```

There is no need to use an array in either case, as you don't need the seprate values in the end, you only need the sum of the values.

Comment: Great answer @Guffa! I noticed the broken behavior in rarely generating the `min` value.  Also, big +1 for pointing out that the array is unnecessary, that's a relief.

Comment: @Guffa, You'd better change =+ to += in your first variant. Otherwise it'll look like you don't test your code.

Comment: Just to re-iterate since other answers are bubbling to the top.  This is definitely the best method.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you don't really need a recursive solution since you tagged this `for-loop`. This will return the number of times the max number was picked:

```
function generateNum (min, max) {
    var diff = max - min;
    if(diff <= 0)
        return;

    for(var i = 0; diff == Math.floor(Math.random()*(diff + 1)); i++);

    return i;
}
```

Example outputs:

```
generateNum(1,2)  // 3
generateNum(1,2)  // 1
generateNum(1,2)  // 0
generateNum(5,10) // 0
generateNum(5,10) // 1
```

Comment: What is the `if(min == max) \ return;` for in this code?  The `min` paramater is the floor of the range which is 5 - 10 for `generateNum(5,10);`... what would be an example of meeting the  `if(min == max) \ return;` condition?

Comment: @Brian That is a precation to stop it from looping infintely. If `min == max` then max will always be generated and it will continue generating random numbers forever.

Comment: Awesome! Just one small point of clarification: I probably shouldn't be using an array, simply because it's unnecessary. In the end I just want to return the total, which will require another loop to add together the items in `results`.

Comment: @Brian Okay, I made the function return an array, because that is what you asked for. (Also you would not need a loop, you could use array.length), but it is much better to return the number of occurrences if that is all you need. I will update my answer.

Comment: No worries, I realize that is what I asked for.  Apologies that @Guffa was able to see a mistake in what I was asking for, I've got to give him the official nod so that someone else doesn't make my mistake.  Leave yours as is though, since it presents a different solution.

Comment: @Brian Oh oops I already edited it haha. I can roll back if you want me to, but you might find an updated answer that protects against infinite loops interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive method:

```
function generateNum (min, max) {
  var res = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

  return (res === max) ? [res].concat(generateNum(min, max)) : res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) the probability to roll 10 stays (theoretically the same on each roll (re-try)), the low probability is of hitting n times 10 in a row

2) I don't see why recursion is needed, what about a while loop?

```
 var randNumber;
 var arr = [];
 while ((randNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(max - min)+min)) === max) {
   arr.push(
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider an idea that you don't need to use not only recursion and arrays but not even a for loop.
I think you need a simple expression like this one (separated into three for clarity):

```
function generateNum (min, max)
{
    var randTail = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min)+min);
    var randRepeatMax = Math.floor(Math.log(Math.random()) / Math.log(1/(max-min+1)));
    return randRepeatMax*max + randTail;
}
```

Assuming one random number is as good as another, this should give you the same distribution of values as the straightforward loop.